# Problem with CORS policy when I use axios POST

Tags: javascript, java, vue.js, axios, cors

I'm implementing a project using vue.js for the front-end and a RESTful webservice (implemented with Grizzly and Jersey) to the backend side. I implemented two API accessible one with a GET request and the other with a POST request. On the front-end side I use axios to execute the requests.
**Both the api calls work with Postman**.

From the backend I created a filter that permits to add some headers as "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to the server response.

```java
    public class MyFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request,
            ContainerResponseContext response) throws IOException {
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "CSRF-Token, X-Requested-By, Authorization, Content-Type");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
    }
}
```

and I used the ResourceConfig *"register"* method to register it.
When I execute the GET request I don't have problems and I acquire the resource correctly.
My problem is related with the POST request, because I get these errors when I execute it:

[image]

The first error says that *"No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present in the requested resource"* , despite it is included in my response and I can see that using Postman (and moreover the GET request works).

I tried to execute POST requests to the correspondent fake apis exposed here https://reqres.in/ and they work.

This is the axios POST:
2

```javascript
    axios.post("http://localhost:8089/tec/resource",this.surveyValues)
```

where surveyValues is a javascript object.

This is the resource on the backend side:

```java
    @Path("resource")
    public class Resource {
        
        @Context
          private Configuration configuration;
            CoreEngine coreComputation;
        /**
         * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
         * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
         *
         * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
         */
        @POST
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public ResponseBody getIt(JsonSurvey survey) {
            
            Map<String,Double> initAssessmentMap = new HashMap<String,Double>();
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            CollectionMongoDB mongoDB = new CollectionMongoDB();
            mongoDB = (CollectionMongoDB) this.configuration.getProperty("mongoDB");
            this.coreComputation = new CoreEngine();
            initAssessmentMap = this.coreComputation.InitialComputation(survey,mongoDB);
            List<SecurityControls> securityControls = null;
            try {
                securityControls = mapper.readValue(this.coreComputation.getSecurityControls().toString(),new TypeReference<List<SecurityControls>>() {});
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ResponseBody response = new ResponseBody(securityControls, initAssessmentMap);
            
            return response;
            
        }
```

Hope that you could help me!

Comment: 1. I added the Java tag for you because 2. this probably has nothing to do with axios and 3. the fact that it works in postman doesn't mean anything, postman is not a web page so doesn't have an origin to have a cross origin policy for.

Comment: Your server needs to properly respond to the CORS preflight request which is sent prior to your POST.

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework in java, would probably help.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8081")` annotation (of your URL the request is coming from) to the class, like;

```
@Path("resource")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
    public class Resource { ... }
```

For more details, see [Enabling Cross Origin Requests for a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)